# Automate setting git-credential-osxkeychain

Tags: git, macos, ansible, keychain

I've got a bit of a niche use case.

I manage a cluster of MacOS CI servers through Ansible. One task I need to accomplish to configure this cluster would be to set credentials for HTTPS rather than SSH for cloning a Git repository.

I need to be able to set the credentials without having to manually enter the credential the first time on each server to perform the osxkeychain link. Below is the Ansible role I'm developing to handle this.

```
---
  - name: Unlock Keychain
    shell: ~/scripts/keychain_unlock.sh

  - name: Set keychain to use git
    shell: git config --global credential."{{ git_protocol }}://{{ bitbucket_server }}".username {{ bitbucket_username }}

  - name: Check if password exists
    shell: security find-internet-password -a ${bitbucket_username} -s ${bitbucket_server}
    ignore_errors: true
    register: credential_exists

  - name: Delete password if it already exists
    shell: security delete-internet-password -a {{ bitbucket_username }} -s "{{ bitbucket_server }}"
    ignore_errors: true 
    when: credential_exists.rc != 0

  - name: Set Bitbucket Credentials on the Keychain
    shell: security add-internet-password -a {{ bitbucket_username }} -s "{{ bitbucket_server }}" -w "{{ bitbucket_password }}" -r htps -T "{{ git_credential_keychain }}"
```

So far this role does the following:

- Sets the username for the Bitbucket instance in `.gitconfig`
- Sets an internet password on the keychain for the user on the Bitbucket instance.

I still get prompted for a Bitbucket password on the initial clone run (It's a repository consumed through a Cocoapods install). How can I automate this so it's completely automated through Ansible?